# Bitmap still null even when assigning BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream) to it

Tags: android

i want to load image from mysql database and display it in an imageView. so i tried this code. but i see that Bitmap object does not get any thing from methode decodeStram. and that is what i see in logcat :

> W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>
> OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe99e1140, error=EGL_SUCCESS
>
> D/skia: ---SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

**Code :**

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap b) {
            super.onPostExecute(b);
            loading.dismiss();
            imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            String id = params[0];
            String add = "http://192.168.1.30/save/load_image_from_db.php?id="+id;
            URL url;
            Bitmap image = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(add);
                HttpURLConnection connection  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BufferedInputStream buffer=new BufferedInputStream(is);
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer, null, options);

                // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer,null,options);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return image;
        }
    }
```

this also does not work, i'v been searching all the day and no solution!

```
try {
                url = new URL(add);
                HttpURLConnection connection  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());
                Log.d("jajajaj",connection.getInputStream().available()+"");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: http://192.168.1.30/save/load_image_from_db.php?id=1, i tried this in browser it loads image but in android apps i get error

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to read the InputStream twice.  You can't do that because the first decodeStream will consume some of the input in order to give you the first answer you're looking for.  The second decode is then working with an invalid image stream.  Instead, skip the first decode and just go straight for the image, since you have to read the stream anyway.

Comment: image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());

in the begening i wrote juste one line, but i get the same error even with this line.

Comment: Then the input is not a valid image that Android can decode. Try dumping its contents to a file on sdcard and copy it to your computer to make sure.

Comment: but if the image stored in database is properly displayed in the browser using php, this does not mean that the image is valid and should be decoded by android o.O?

Comment: There are a lot of things between your database and Android.  Read the contents and dump it to a file to see if everything works as you expect.  Make sure it is also one of the image file formats Android can decode.

Comment: hmm i don't realy know how to do what you are proposing

Comment: Bottom line is that you're going to have to debug this HTTP transaction because it's probably not generating what you expect.